# Assign different ids to buttons and call a function with its data

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, foreach, fetch

I have little experience in js and got stuck. I´m creating a table with the results of an api request where each row is a result and have a button that I have to associate with its data to call a function.
How can I assign different ids to each botton and associate its data?

Here is my code, I'd appreciate any help

```
fetch...
.then((data) => {
    hideSpinner();
    console.log(bodyString);
    let resultrows = data.ResultRows;
    if (resultrows.length == 0) {
      document.querySelector("#error").innerHTML = "No se encontraron resultados. Por favor verifique los criterios de búsqueda y vuelva a intentar.";
    } else {
    resultrows.forEach(async (element) => {
      let fechaa = element.CDay_id;
      console.log(fechaa);
      let sucu = element.OpPoint_id;
      console.log(sucu);
      let cajero = element.Checker_id;
      console.log(cajero);
      let cajaa = element.Checkout_id;
      console.log(cajaa);
      let dniCrf = element.AffinityCardNbr_id;
      console.log(dniCrf);
      let numop = element.OperationNbr_id;
      console.log(numop);
      $('#bodyTera').append(
        `<tr>
                <td>${fechaa}</td>
                <td>${dniCrf}</td>
                <td>${cajaa}</td>
                <td>${sucu}</td>
                <td>${numop}</td>
                <td>${cajero}</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-dark">Ver</button></td>
                </tr>`);
    });
```

Comment: I’m a little confused about what you’re trying to achieve. What do you mean by “associating” the data in this context, and what do you want the buttons to do when you click them?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try to be more clear. Every time the user click the button "ver" it should call a function to make another api request using the data of that row in the body. So by "associating" I mean the button should keep the data of the row so that can call the function and pass it

Comment: Gotcha. Can you not just use the variables you’ve already set, or are you trying to make this something that could be clicked over and over again, continually updating the variables like a recursive function? I think it would understand more if I knew what the API is doing, or at least what the data it is giving you is. Are you calling the same API or is this two separate APIs?